# Remove div tags in python

Tags: python, html, web-scraping

I'm trying to remove div tags in python. I have something like:

```
<div class="header-top">
<div class="font-t3 font-primary font-weight-700" id="name">John Smith</div>
<div class="font-t5 font-secondary nobr" id="gender">Male</div>
</div>
```

And I just want to extract the information as variables:

```
name = 'John Smith'
sex = 'Male'
```

or as a list `(John Smith, Male)`

Comment: No I get AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'body'. You're probably treating a list of elements like a single element. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?

Comment: And I'm using find()